# Calculate time gaps in SQL vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the  following data set:

```
(StartTime,EndTime)
(2,2.30)
(3,4.30)
(5,6)
```

I need to consider the time gaps in between
What I need:

```
(2,2.30)
(2.30,3)
(3,4.30)
(4.30,5)
(5,6)
```

How can I achieve this in SQL.
I am using vertica database.

Comment: I have tried lead/lag and created new rows.
Wanted to check whether there is any better way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically need to use `LEAD` to generate the rows in between.  There is also time series for GFI but it doesn't really fit this problem too well honestly because you are dealing with ranges of time, not static slices.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (StartTime interval,EndTime interval)

INSERT into mytable VALUES  ( INTERVAL '2 minutes', INTERVAL '2.5 minutes');
INSERT into mytable VALUES  ( INTERVAL '3 minutes', INTERVAL '4.5 minutes');
INSERT into mytable VALUES  ( INTERVAL '5 minutes', INTERVAL '6 minutes');

SELECT StartTime, EndTime 
from mytable
union all
SELECT EndTime, lead (StartTime, 1) OVER (order by StartTime)
from mytable
order by 1
```

You'll end up with a record at the end indicating an open range which you can filter out if you don't want it. You can also add in another union to get a similar before time record as well if you want that.